# Убрать шумы с фото для дальнейшего распознавания текста

Tags: python, python-3.x, изображения, распознавание-символов, распознавание

Требуется распознать текст с помощью Python.

Мой выбор остановился на библиотеке `pytesseract`, но она просто ужасно справляется со своей задачей, если на тексте есть хоть какие-то шумы.

---

*Примеры фото:*

[image: jrd - Someday]
[image: aimless - we'll go to the beach]
[image: saiko - asleep]

Ожидаемые результаты:

1. jrd - Someday
2. aimless - we'll go to the beach
3. saiko - asleep

Если не распознается пунктуация, то ничего страшного. Это названия песен, поэтому не критично.

*Примечание: Фото брал с [YouTube-стрима](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHW1oY26kxQ), задний фон может меняться, но вариантов всего несколько.*

---

Первые попытки:

```py
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('text.png'), lang='eng'))
```

Код не напечатал ничего во всех случаях. Полностью обезнадёживающий результат.

Конечно, я не остановился и попробовал все ответы из похожего [англоязычного вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37745519/11558617), но результат не изменился. Проблема в том, что на моих фото очень большой контраст.

Я предполагаю, что необходимо подобрать правильный фильтр. Шрифт годен для распознавания и к тому же белый. Но совсем в этом не разбираюсь.

Буду рад, если подскажете, как именно можно фильтровать подобные фото, на какие библиотеки стоит обратить внимание или же какие материалы мне стоит искать в интернете.

Comment: Если фонов конечное количество, то их можно тупо все собрать и вычитать

Comment: @andreymal Я об этом думал, но навряд ли смогу достать чистые фоны. Левая часть всегда будет занята каким-то текстом и её придётся распознавать.

Comment: Текст занимает картинку не целиком и всегда по разному, так что можно попробовать вытащить фон из разных картинок, удалить текст в ближайшем фотошопе, а остатки слепить вместе https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFcWm.png

Comment: А вообще текст примечателен тем, что он ярче фона, так что можно попробовать из HSL/HSV вытащить яркость и сделать с этим что-нибудь https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pPIC.png

Comment: @andreymal Последний пример успешно распознался. Спасибо за отличный вариант. Постараюсь детальнее изучить эту тему. И, если не сложно, подскажите, пожалуйста, чем Вы пользовались, чтобы получить его?

Comment: Просто в GIMP разобрал цвет на слои HSV, вытащил слой с яркостью и все тёмные участки свёл в черноту, чтобы остался только текст. Думаю, можно повторить то же самое с Pillow, но мне лень пробовать (а также гуглить, как в Pillow работать с HSV, хех)

Comment: Хотя, может, даже HSV не нужно и достаточно просто картинку в оттенки серого перевести (что по сути тоже яркость), но экспериментировать в этом направлении тоже лень

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import cv2                #   pip install opencv
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
from pytesseract import image_to_string

def get_white_mask(
  img,
  lower=np.array([200,200,200]),
  upper=np.array([255,255,255])):
    return cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)

def ocr(img_url, **tess_kwargs):
    img = get_white_mask(cv2.imread(img_url))
    return image_to_string(img, **tess_kwargs)
```

тесты:

```
In [9]: ocr(r"D:\download\img1.png")
Out[9]: 'jrd — Someday'

In [10]: ocr(r"D:\download\img2.png")
Out[10]: "aimless — we'll go to the beach"

In [11]: ocr(r"D:\download\img3.png")
Out[11]: 'saiko - asleep'
```

---

конвертирование картинок:

```
path = Path(r"D:\download")

_ = [cv2.imwrite(str(f.parent / (f.stem + "_mask" + f.suffix)),
                 get_white_mask(cv2.imread(str(f))))
     for f in path.glob("img*.png")]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое, Вы мне очень помогли. Тема очень интересная, постараюсь больше её изучить! Я поэкспериментировал с весами, для меня оптимальным вариантом оказались стартовые значения [150, 150, 150]. Если интересно, то вот, что в итоге у меня получилось: https://pastebin.com/VhgHzK4T

Comment: Лучше  привести текст к виду черные символы на белом фоне.